# RoR string from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string

I have an array of hashes generated by `map`

```
arr = current_order.order_items.map{|oi|[{name:oi.name,price:oi.price}]

[{:name=>"Jacket", :price=>300},
 {:name=>"Bag", :price=>650 },
 {:name=>"Suit", :price=>300}].to_s
```

i need to make a string from it like this

```
name: Jacket,price:300
name: Bag,price:650
name: Suit,price:300
```

What i did it `gsub` every needed element like  `gsub(':size=>','size:')`

but it looks very ugly

Need more convenient solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If keys are predetermined:

```
arr.map { |item| "name:#{ item[:name] }, price:#{ item[:price] }" }.join("\n")
```

If not:

```
arr.map { |item| item.map { |k, v| "#{ k }:#{ v }" }.join(', ')  }.join("\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

1. Define a function on a hash to pretty print it for you.
2. `map` over the array to gain pretty printed strings for each.

   ```
   def pretty_print(hash)
     hash.map {|key, value| "#{key}: #{value}"}.join(', ')
   end
   arr.map {|hash| pretty_print(hash)}
   ```